# What happens to permission structure of classic site when you add an O365 group?

Tags: office-365, site-collection, office-365-groups

On classic sites there is 'Connect to new O365 group'. What happens to the permissions of the site (in the case you have Site Members set on Contribute and Site Visitors set on View only) when you connect it to an O365 group?

Also, in case you have deleted the ugly Documents (aka Shared%20Documents) and created others with other names, what happens when you connect? does it create another Documents that is the 'Files' of the group?